# Using bower_components with Grunt

Tags: angularjs, node.js, npm, gruntjs, bower

I created a simple data listing app using angular js.
I used Bower and also grunt. Grunt to serve the project with a specific port. But have a error.. When i'm serve the project with Grunt, the bower_components are not working. I mean all the jquery and also angular parts get 404. I here by attach a link to my project.

[Get my project here - https://github.com/chanakaDe/DemoApp](https://github.com/chanakaDe/DemoApp)

First clone it, then "npm install" and then "bower install".
Please tell me how to make them work.
Always get 404 errors like this
GET http://localhost:1701/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js 404

[image]

Comment: Are you sure you imported angular files?

Comment: @Jagrut Yeah I'm sure :) I added them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're specifying `./src` as the root of your server in the Gruntfile. Unfortunately, bower installs it's dependencies a folder above it, in the root of your project. Your HTML has a couple of script tags with `../bower_components/[path to files]`, but this will not work.

You need to try to install the bower dependencies in your `src` folder. Add a `.bowerrc` file in the root of your project with the following content:

```
{
  "directory" : "src/bower_components"
}
```

Then reinstall bower dependencies by doing:

```
$ bower install
```

Check if a folder `bower_components` have been created in your `src` folder.

Next replace `../bower_components` with `bower_components` in the `index.html` file.

Comment: No problem, glad I could help.